# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '78.60 ' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT 
    CAST(AVG(CAST(hum AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
FROM [tablelog] 
WHERE hum = ISNUMERIC(hum)
```

and it throws an error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '78.60 ' to data type int.

`hum` column is set to a `varchar(50)` as datatype.. can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(hum as DECIMAL(10,2))) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM [tablelog] 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(hum)=1
```

The where clause in your query is wrong, ISNUMERIC() always return 0(if false) or 1(if true)

**Change** `where hum = ISNUMERIC(hum)` **to**  `where ISNUMERIC(hum)=1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `where hum = ISNUMERIC(hum)`

ISNUMERIC returns int so the error is caused when trying to equate hum (varchar) with the result of ISNUMERIC(hum) (int). Also ISNUMERIC returns 0 or 1 (for true or false) so maybe this isn't the function you want?